# Why is Firefox ignoring -moz-box-sizing and box-sizing?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS class:

```
#CenterColumnWrapper
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="CenterColumnWrapper"><div>
```

When I test this in Chrome and Opera everything is okay, but when I test it in Firefox, it ignores the `box-sizing`.

Why? And what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Firefox has supported it for [quite some time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing). Is this all of your CSS?

Comment: Yeah the quickest guess is that this is being overridden by some other style, or you're using a much older version of FF (unlikely...).
Post the rest of your styles if there are any.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you testing with?

Comment: Hey, leave a [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) example so we can get the code in context. And doing this may just help you find your error.

Comment: Have a look to this link http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ they have written...

Comment: `-ms-` and `-o-` don't exist for `box-sizing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to see why Firefox is ignoring your CSS is to use the Firebug addon. With Firebug you can see what part of the CSS is applied to a certain element, in this case the `#CenterColumnWrapper`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i check it and found my fault.